# I cannot log in

Tags: login, intel, login-screen, acer, gnome-tweaks

I've been using Ubuntu for a few weeks and today I modified/tweaked it. I restarted my laptop and now I cannot log in. I try to log in but it takes me back to the log in screen. I don't want to lose any data on this laptop.

**[EDIT] I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME extensions:.

Dash to Panel

Dash to Dock

Arc Menu**
***[EDIT#2] I TURNED OFF THE "TURN OFF TRACK PAD WHILE TYPING" IN TWEAKS SETTINGS***

Comment: Being specific as to what changes/tweaks you made will help us understand your issue. You've not provided Ubuntu product/release details; but adding a GNOME extension intended for a different release/version of GNOME shell can cause shell crash & logout. Also simply conditions as lack of disk space in $HOME (your user directory) can prevent a GUI login (but you'll be able to login via text terminal to explore issue & correct; ie. create space by removing files). What release are you using? and what modifications/tweaks did you make?

Comment: I used Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I wanted to make Ubuntu look like windows 11 but the tweaks glitched and I couldn't enable some of them so I restarted the laptop and I got logged out. Yes. I used Gnome extensions.

Comment: Please add the additional detail to your question, ie. your release details, plus what gnome extensions you added.  Have you logged in via text terminal and ensured you have disk space in $HOME, ie. `df -hl` to view disk.free space on local drives; particularly your home partition where lack of free space will prevent a GUI login (but not text terminal logins).

Comment: You have to login via terminal, and remote the `.Xauthority` file from your home directory. Press `ctrl-alt-F2`, type in your username and password, and type `rm .Xauthority`.

Comment: It says that this file or folder does not exist

Comment: This question is kind of unclear. What do GNOME Extensions have to do with not being able to log into your computer? Also, you must explain what you mean by you "tweaked" it. If you mean that by "tweaking" it, you installed GNOME Extensions and turned off trackpad while typing, that doesn't have anything to do with booting and logging on. Please edit your question to add clarity or delete it alltogether.